# Computing electric flux through a Gaussian cube

Tags: python, numpy, math, physics

I'm attempting to write a simple `Python` script which computes the flux due to a point charge of `1 statocoulumb` at the origin through a cube centered on the origin with side lengths `2`, using Riemann integration (I'm aware that in doing so I've recreated many utilities built-in to `Python` and `NumPy`).

To do so, I've defined functions `dot(vec0, vec1)` (which returns the dot product of two `NumPy` arrays/vectors), `da(x,y,z,dx,dy,dz)` (which returns a differential area vector), and `Evector(x,y,z)` (which returns the electric field vector at a point due to a point charge at the origin). I then "integrate" over one face of the cube (the top face, with area vector pointing in the `+z` direction) with a simple Riemann integration, expecting to find a flux of `(1/6) 4π` (from Gauss' Law). Instead, I find `~0.006`. Unfortunately, it isn't clear to me why (note that this does not improve with an increase or decrease in the number of Riemann divisions (i.e. `xstepmax, ystepmax, zstepmax`).

Where have I erred?

```
import numpy as np

q=1 # 1 statocoulomb

def dot(vec0, vec1):
    return vec0 @ vec1

def da(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz):
    return np.array([x*dy*dz, y*dx*dz, z*dx*dy])

def Evector(x, y, z):
    r2 = x**2 + y**2 + z**2
    return np.array([x, y, z]) * (q / r2)

# Define bounds of integration for x, y, and z
xmin = -1
xmax = 1
ymin = -1
ymax = 1
zmin = -1
zmax = 1

# Define number of steps for x, y, and z
xstepmax = 101
ystepmax = 101
zstepmax = 101

# Define step size for x, y, and z
dx = (xmax-xmin)/xstepmax
dy = (ymax-ymin)/ystepmax
dz = (zmax-zmin)/zstepmax

# Initial value of flux
flux = 0

for xsteps in range(0,xstepmax):
    x =  xmin + (dx * xsteps) # Current x value, starting at xmin and increasing by dx with each iteration

    for ysteps in range(0,ystepmax):
        y = ymin + (dy * ysteps) # Current y value, starting at ymin and increasing by dy with each iteration
                flux += dot(Evector(x,y,1), da(x,y,1,dx,dy,0)) * dx * dy # dot(E,da) * dx * dy 

print(flux)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of small mistakes here:

- The numerator of `Evector` should be `r^3` instead of `r^2`, as you must normalise the directional vector (which in this case is the also the displacement from the charge):

  ```
  def Evector(x, y, z):
      rv = np.array([x, y, z])
      r3 = np.dot(rv, rv) ** 1.5
      return rv * (q / r3)
  ```
- Same with the area element vector `dA`:

  ```
  def da(nx, ny, nz, dx, dy, dz):
      return np.array([nx*dy*dz, ny*dx*dz, nz*dx*dy]) \
           / np.linalg.norm(np.array([nx, ny, nz]))
  ```
- As you're integrating over the top surface, the normal should be `(0,0,1)` and not `(x,y,1)`. Also there is no need to multiply by `dx * dy` again since the area element is the magnitude of `da`:

  ```
  flux += np.dot(Evector(x,y,1), da(0,0,1,dx,dy,0))   # dot(E,da)
  ```

Result:

```
theory: 2.0943951023931953 (= 4*pi/6)
actual: 2.094294486403918
```